# Switch from Ubuntu 13.04 64bit to 32bit

Tags: installation, 64-bit, 32-bit

Actually after reading my problem, most of you will laugh at me. I myself am, for such a stupid mistake.
What exactly happened was, I was downloading 32-bit version of Ubuntu 13.04 for my old PC. After downloading, one of my friend also wanted Ubuntu 13.04, although his PC had a 64-bit hardware. So I thought of downloading 64-bit version too. But mistakenly, instead of writing the ia64 version onto his USB drive, I wrote the 64-bit OS, replacing my 32-bit one.
And I gave him a blank pen drive.

While installing Ubuntu, I certainly felt something was different. Different in the sense, that it was taking to much time to load. And then while using Gnome Tweak Tool, I found out it actually was 64 bit.

And I have also changed my HDD, so I don't have the ISO files any more. So any way to go to 32-bit without losing data or anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that there is a good way to downgrade to 32bit. You can however install ia32-libs-multiarch to add 32bit support to the 64bit OS:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch
```

[source](http://shtuff.it/article/17/Ubuntu-Run-32-bit-applications-on-64-bit-OS-install)

Comment: Actually. my PC has a 32-bit processor. It features and old Pentium-4 3.06gHz processor. So would using the above code in the Terminal just solve all the speed related problems that I am facing in the 64-bit version?

Comment: You would not have been able to install a 64bit OS on a 32bit processor, the install disk would have never booted. Does the system report 64bit with the 'arch' command?

Comment: I didn't exactly try it. Although I simply downloaded and installed a 32-bit Ubuntu 13.04 and installed it.
The only things that I noticed were that the boot-up & shut down time was reduced. They were faster than they were previously.
Else everything is the same.

Comment: Apart from that, the only thing that I noticed was that in every update, it was downloading x86_64 packages, and no x86 packages. Only x86_64. That also made me doubt. And also, my PC is very old (about 8 years old) so that makes me doubt that it features a 64bit processor. PC: HP Pavilion a1220in

Comment: Sounds like you have a 64bit processor. To confirm that you infact have a 64bit OS run the 'arch' command from the CLI. To find out more about the processor you have installed 'cat /proc/cpuinfo'.

Comment: 'arch' command gave me 'i686'. I think that is because I have reinstalled a 32bit version of ubuntu.
In the other code, the result had only one thing with "64" in it, and it was clflush size. What do you think?

Comment: And sorry for the really late reply.